# What API replaces gtkembedmoz?

Tags: c, api, gtk, xulrunner, gecko

I have an old piece of software that uses gtkembedmoz, and I need to update it to run on ubuntu lucid, which does not provide that library. What API replaces the functionality that it provides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [WebkitGTK](http://www.webkitgtk.org/) these days for embedding a web browser into a GTK program.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Embedding Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Embedding_FAQ/Embedding_Gecko) page, [GtkMozEmbed](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/gtk-embedding.html) is the preferred way to embed Mozilla into a GTK program.

The Embedding page was last updated in 2008.

The GtkMozEmbed page was last updated in 2006, but still speaks of prehistoric versions like M16.  M16 is a few versions behind Mozilla 0.6.  Yes, 0.6.  That's from the year 2000.

Good luck.

Comment: Mozilla is not embeddable anymore. This change came with the 4.0 release.

Comment: Oh wow, I thought they were only *thinking* about doing that.  Didn't think they'd actually go through with it.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla is embeddable in Lucid using the python-gtkmozembed library. I'm porting the app from C to python using that, and it seems to be working so far.